# Image Upload Using Web View

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Getting an error while trying to upload an image from camera (ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) using a webview. But it's working when I select the image from Files (ACTION_GET_CONTENT).

*URL of File trying to upload from ACTION_GET_CONTENT: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A451*

URL of File trying to upload from ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
*file:/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20220719_162050_5643059705926048051.jpg*

For some reason the web view couldn't access the file generated for ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE. Should I convert this to a Content URI to make it work?

Here is the code for creating the file for ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    return imageFile;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By *"Getting an error while trying to upload an image from camera (ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) using a webview."* might you be asking how to get a photo taken by the device's Camera and then use it on the WebView? If that is the case, find the code below.

**XML Code**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Java Code**

I am making use of [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) to set my View.

```
   public class ImageUploadUsingWebView extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageUploadUsingWebviewBinding imageUploadUsingWebviewBinding; //ViewBinder
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
    };
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> fileCallback;
    int IMG_CAPTURE_REQUEST = 1000;
    int FILE_REQUEST = 2000;
    String CAMERA_FILE_PATH, INTENT_PHOTO = "intent_photo";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        imageUploadUsingWebviewBinding = ImageUploadUsingWebviewBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(imageUploadUsingWebviewBinding.getRoot());

        if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, 1);
        }

        initWebView(imageUploadUsingWebviewBinding.webView);

        imageUploadUsingWebviewBinding.webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> valueCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                if (fileCallback != null) {
                    fileCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                fileCallback = valueCallback;

                Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePhotoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    File photoPath = null;
                    try {
                        photoPath = createImg();
                        takePhotoIntent.putExtra(INTENT_PHOTO, CAMERA_FILE_PATH);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(ImageUploadUsingWebView.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    if (photoPath != null) {
                        CAMERA_FILE_PATH = "file:" + photoPath.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                Uri.fromFile(photoPath));
                    } else {
                        takePhotoIntent = null;
                    }
                }

                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

                Intent[] _arryIntent;
                if (takePhotoIntent != null) {
                    _arryIntent = new Intent[]{takePhotoIntent};
                } else {
                    _arryIntent = new Intent[0];
                }
                Intent makeChoiceIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                makeChoiceIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                makeChoiceIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Choose Camera");
                makeChoiceIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, _arryIntent);
                startActivityForResult(makeChoiceIntent, FILE_REQUEST);

                return true;
            }
        });
        if (imageUploadUsingWebviewBinding.webView.getUrl() == null) {
            imageUploadUsingWebviewBinding.webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
        }

    }

    private void initWebView(WebView webView) {
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }



    private File createImg() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_mmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "TEST_PHOTO" + timeStamp + "-";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,
                ".jpg",
                storageDir
        );
        return imageFile;
    }

    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri[] onActivityResult = null;
            onActivityResult = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(CAMERA_FILE_PATH)};
            fileCallback.onReceiveValue(onActivityResult);
            fileCallback = null;
            Toast.makeText(ImageUploadUsingWebView.this, "Image picked from camera sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<input type="file" id="files" class="hidden"/>
<label for="files">Get photo from camera</label>
</body>
</html>
```

The html file is in the assets folder

[image]

Regards